# How can I create stub Junit tests in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, junit

Is there a simple way of creating stubs for Junit4 tests in Eclipse (Galileo)?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

In the *Package Explorer* view, right-click on the file that you would like to create a JUnit test for. In the opened context menu, select *New* -> *Other...* . In the *Select a wizard* dialog, select *Java* -> *JUnit* -> *JUnit Test Case* .

Then a dialog opens. In case you have a default *Maven* or *Gradle* project, you will probably have to change the default *Source folder* from the provided `${PROJECT_NAME}/src/main/java` to `${PROJECT_NAME}/src/test/java`. If you click *Next*, the dialog allows you to check which methods to automatically create stubs for.

Answer (score 7):

You might also look into [Fast Code Eclipse Plugin](http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/). Once you configure you can generate junit/testng test by selecting the class or any method. Also gives you way to navigate from a method to all the tests.

[image]