# Generating JUnit stubs for new methods in existing class in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, junit

This question is tangentially related to [How can I create JUnit stub methods in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894298/how-can-i-create-stub-junit-tests-in-eclipse) but it doesn't answer my specific question.

Assuming you have an existing JUnit test case class, if you add a method to the target class (or choose to test a previously untested method), is there a way to tell Eclipse to generate the stub for the "new" method(s) in the existing TestCase without creating a new test case class?

Answer (score 5):

1. Install the MoreUnit extension from the MarketPlace.
2. Open the package hierarchy panel.
3. Navigate down to the class that
   you've modified.
4. Right click on the new method.
5. Select "Generate Test". The generated stub will appear in your ClassTest file.

Comment: Are you using a plugin of some sort? I don't see the "Generate Test" option in Eclipse using your procedure...

Comment: How the MoreUnit can add new test case for only newly added method into the existing test class? I tried, it seems cannot do that. For generate a new test class, Eclipse can do it by itself without MoreUnit.

Comment: MoreUnit doesn't work if the test classes are in a different 'project' - just flags the class as already existing - at which point it fails.
Shame - it would be useful otherwise. (So I'll uninstall again.)

Answer (score 3):

My solution.

I simply go through the standard 'create JUnit test case'

Select file to test. -> New Junit test case

Go through the normal process in creating the test case, but only select those that you want new stubs for.

The file is created with the stubs, which I now copy into the existing test case file.
Delete the newly created test file class.

It's not the most efficient, but quicker than 'thick fingering' when you create them manually.

David

Comment: A bit more tedious than the process should be, but works for me for now!

Answer (score 2):

The usual working cycle with unit tests is to create the test case first

```
public void test_new_method() {
    ClassUnderTest x = new ClassUnderTest();
    x.NewMethod();
}
```

At that point Eclipse will give you a warning that the method "NewMethod" does not exist. Than you simply select a "Quick Fix" (Ctrl-1 or Ctrl-2 i'm not sure) to create the missing method in the class.

Comment: Good point, but that doesn't answer my initial question. Eclipse generates the stubs for new test case classes, why can't it generate method stubs for existing classes?

Comment: Sorry for not answering the question but the in Eclipse they (whoever) assume you're working test driven...so test first and then the code...I just checked the help of Eclipse and couldn't find a possibility to do it the way you like it...sorry.

Comment: From the book of "we'll only make it easy for you if you do it our way."

Comment: Also a problem when adding tests for methods that other (non-test first) developers created