# Eclipse JUnit test wizard, creating test methods afterwards

Tags: eclipse, junit, wizard, testcase

In the wizard for creating a new JUnit Test Case, the second step consist of choosing which methods of the class under test you want to test, and it automatically creates an empty test method in the test class.

If you forgot to do this second step, or accidentally pressed "Finish" instead of "Next", is there a way to create those methods after the test class has been created?
Or the only way to do it is to delete the created test class and repeat the process?

Comment: How about just writing the methods you need yourself?

Comment: @t0mppa Writing 50 methods stubs you mean? Actually, repeating the process is what I do now, but if there were a Menu option to redo that second step I would use it instead.

Comment: Write one stub & copy/paste?

Comment: @t0mppa It is not practical, if you used this wizard you know it names the test stub based on the method it tests and its arguments. I would end writing the stubs myself if I cut& paste.

Comment: Guess I just don't see the point in creating one test method for each method of your class under test, when generally you want to have more than one test per method with different outcomes and by the book you write the tests first then the real classes, but never mind that. Would this by any chance be a duplicate of [Generating JUnit stubs for new methods in existing class in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024942/generating-junit-stubs-for-new-methods-in-existing-class-in-eclipse)?

Comment: @t0mppa Yes, it seems to be a duplicate. Although I did not find a satisfactory answer there. I'll stick with redoing the whole process. Thanks

Comment: Even using TDD, as soon as you create a unit test for a non-existent method, Eclipse will urge you to create the method stub in the class under test. Either way, you're not going 'by the book'.

When working on an existing code base where there maybe are not unit tests for everything, then it becomes really useful to be able to create at least one junit test stub to get things started.

'Redoing the whole process' also doesn't work if you already have a substantial suite of tests.