# How Should I write JUnit test in the following case?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am new in the Unit Testing.
I have a class `Ckeckout` which main function is to print the amount to be paid for books. The user types the titles of the books in the command line, and based on some calculations I have to output the final price.
Here is the `Book` class:

```
public class Book {
    private String title;
    private double price;
    private int year;

    public Book(String title, double price, int year) {
        super();
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

And here is the `Checkout` class:

```
public class Checkout {

    private List<Book> books;

    public Checkout(List<Book> books) {
        super();
        this.books = books;
    }

    //calculate the final price
    private double getPrice(){
        //return some double
    }


}
```

What I want to test is just `getPrice` method. However, to do so, do I have to create list of `Book` objects in my `CheckoutTest`? Also, I will have to verify the final result with some very long number (like 62.01997301). Isn't it easier, to test the main() method, since in my Unit test, there won't be any need to create the `Book` objects (I will work only with `Strings`) and I can verify the output with shorter number (like 62.01)?

Comment: Just want to comment, you probably should not use double to store prices because of the inherent inaccuracy of floating point types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. However, to do so, do I have to create list of Book objects in my CheckoutTest?:Generally and in any kind - **yeah**!
2. Also, I will have to verify the final result with some very long number (like 62.01997301): **Naah**, *this* depends on your targeting test/code quality! (for a "price" 2 digits should be sufficient (in any country!?))
3. Isn't it easier, to test the main() method, since in my Unit test, there won't be any need to create the Book objects (I will work only with Strings) and I can verify the output with shorter number (like 62.01)? **Definitely!** But with the current setup some (human) would have to check the console for "passing that test", for JUnit(and programmatically testing the value), you should/will need to make "getPrice() more visible" ... or in some way access its value.

Comment: Thanks! And if I want to test several cases, I should write several `test()` methods, right?

Comment: Sounds ok to me! At testing it is "not so important" how you do it, but "that" you do it, and how much (program) code you cover. The standard tools (eclipse, netbeans, ...) have(had) a wizard for Test(Stub) generation - the normal setup is one TestClass per Class, one testMethod per (public) method. Here some links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894298/how-can-i-create-stub-junit-tests-in-eclipse, http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076265/testing-debugging/junit-best-practices.html ...